# Word signature in factor

Tags: stack, factor-lang

i try to iterate over a an array which contains weather data. That works fine already and I also can load the datas from the array which are important for me. Therefore I wrote a helping word which looks like this:

`: get-value ( hsh str -- str ) swap at* drop ;`

`[ "main" get-value "temp" get-value ] each 9 [ + ] times`

This code pushes the temperature values from the array on the stack and builds the sum. "main" and "temp" are the key values of the arrays.

I execute it with this command: get-weather-list generates the array

`"Vienna" get-weather-list [ "main" get-value "temp" get-value ] each 9 [ + ] times`

The result is a number on the stack. Now I want to split this call into one or two words. For example:

`: get-weather-information ( city -- str )
     get-weather-list
     [ "main" get-value "temp" get-value ] each 9 [ + ] times ;`

The problem is that I don't really understand the word's signature. I always get "The input quotation to “each” doesn't match its expected effect". I tried a lot but can't find a solution to fix this problem. May anyone have an idea? I am grateful for any help :)

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question by now, but it still may be useful to someone.

First, about `each`: the stack effect of the quotation is `(... x -- ...)`.

That means it consumes an input, and outputs nothing. Your quotation worked on the interpreter because it lets you get away with "wrong" code. But for calling each from a defined word, your quotation can't output anything.

So `each` is not what you want. If you try to push a variable amount of values to the stack, you'll have the same kind of trouble again. Sequence words all output a fixed amount of values.

What you want to do is one of two things:

1. Make a new sequence with just the values you want, and then call `sum` on it.
2. Use something like `reduce`, to accumulate the sum as you process your list.

For example, with `reduce`:

```
 get-weather-list 0 [ "main" get-value "temp" get-value + ] reduce ;
```